# Add a class with hover effect in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want creating a website with some small news on the start-page. I show only the pics and show the headline and a small sentence with an hover-effect. Unfortunately I have no experience with jQuery and my code doesn't work.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(this).removeClass("#news-container .newscontent")
});

$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#news-container img").hover(function () {
    $(this).addClass("#news-container .newscontent");
  }, function () {
    $(this).removeClass("#news-container .newscontent");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: A demo would be useful here. Also your snippet has an error in it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to toggle some class or the visibility of some childs with jquery the dom stucture is key. Let's assume you got the following structure:

```
    <div class="newscontent">
        <img class="image" src="...">
        <div class="text">Some text</div>
    </div>
```

The following code registers for the hover event on every image within an element with a *newcontent* class. The image with the hover `$(this)` searches for the next element with a *text* class and toggles the visibility.

```
    $('.newscontent img').hover(function(){
      if ( $(this).next('.text').css('visibility') === 'visible' ){
            $(this).next('.text').css('visibility', 'hidden');
        }else{
            $(this).next('.text').css('visibility', 'visible');
      }
    });
```

You can find a full working example here:
https://jsfiddle.net/3xy8ar96/1/